# Turning curser on and off

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cursor

What I am trying to do is have different NPC menus, the game starts by turning off the curser.  But when you click on the NPC it repeats so you can talk to the NPC.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CursorScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject merchant;
    public GameObject builder;
    public bool canTurnMerchantOn;
    public bool canTurnBuilderOn;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        //Set Cursor to not be visible
        Cursor.visible = false;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    void Update()
    {
       if(builder.activeSelf == true && canTurnBuilderOn)
        {
            Cursor.visible = true;
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
            canTurnMerchantOn = false;
        }

        if (builder.activeSelf == false)
        {
            Cursor.visible = false;
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
            canTurnMerchantOn = true;
        }

        if (merchant.activeSelf == true && canTurnMerchantOn)
        {
            Cursor.visible = true;
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
            canTurnBuilderOn = false;
        }

        if (merchant.activeSelf == false)
        {
            Cursor.visible = false;
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
            canTurnBuilderOn = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The weird thing is the merchant npc works fine, then the builder npc the curser flickers and I cant click anything.

Comment: Something to consider: How does this script know which npc you are clicking on?

Comment: Your biggest issue might be using .activeSelf. It will return true even inf the object is not active in the scene. If a parent object of these objects is deactivated but it is active as a child of this parent, it will return true still. If they are not the root object in the hierarchy, either make sure to disable them specifically or use [gameObject.activeInHierarchy](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-activeInHierarchy.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that the builder’s active self is equal to true, and can turn builder on is also true, the code will turn the cursor on. But that turns the can turn merchant on to false, which would turn the cursor off. The update function calls once per frame, so it will turn the cursor on and off repeatedly. I recommend using an else if instead of all of the if statements, if you don’t want that, you can use return;. Here is the code:

```
void Update()
{
   if(builder.activeSelf == true)
    {
        Cursor.visible = true;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        return;
    }

    else if (builder.activeSelf == false)
    {
        Cursor.visible = false;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    if (merchant.activeSelf == true)
    {
        Cursor.visible = true;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        return;
    }

    else if (merchant.activeSelf == false)
    {
        Cursor.visible = false;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }
}
```

You also don’t need the can turn builder/merchant in code either because of this. If this doesn’t work, you at least know the problem.

Comment: The snippet you posted will not compile. There is no such thing as an `if else` statement in c# nor any language I can think of.

Comment: Sorry, I meant else if. I get it mixed up sometimes.